# adding a new table using rails migration..?

Tags: rails-migrations, ruby-1.8.7

I want to add new table using rails migration:

```
**table_name** users_location_track
**columns** id (primary key, auto increment serial),
            user_id (reference to users), location_info (string), 
            creation_time(time-stamp)
```

please suggest procedure and code I am new to rails?

Comment: It is VERY basic stuff, so I suggest starting from some tutorials/guides, like this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: hey @MarekLipka how can i add ref type while creating table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thank you for criticizing.
Finally I got my answer:

Here's the solution for whoever want in future.

first go to project directory then run following command

```
rails generate migration add_user_lat_long
```

and then a migration file will be generate then you can edit in following style:

```
class AddUserLatLong < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users_location_track do |t|
      t.string :location_info
      t.references :user

      t.timestamps

end
    add_index :users_location_track, :user_id, :name =>'index_user_lat_longs_on_user_id'
  end

  def self.down
        drop_table :users_location_track
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

In Rails You need to write a command like below:

```
 rails generate migration CreateUserLocationTrack user_id:integer location_info:string
```

you don't need `creation_time` as `created_at` is created by default.

For more information, please follow [rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Comment: hey @Manish that much I explored but i want to make user_id as ref type.

Comment: @piyushmandovra, use  `add_foreign_key :users_location_track, :users` and check migration guide for more info.

Comment: so should I have to add another migration or in same migration I can add ref

Comment: @piyushmandovra, you can edit migration before running `rake  db:migrate`